# Soccer Game: Trying to get ball to animate to left or right when button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I'm making a soccer game. When the left button is clicked i want the ball to go to the left of the goalie, and when the right is clicked i want the ball to go to the right. I want the goalie to go opposite for a goal and collide with the ball for a save. I think i'm close but struggling. Here's my main script.

```html
<script>
var ball = null;
var x = 1;
var score = 0;
var gameover;
document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = '0';
var animate;
ball = document.getElementById('ball');
var cheer = new sound('cheer.mp3')

function shootLeft(){
    var ran = Math.random();

    while(parseInt(ball.style.top) != 300){
        ball.style.left = parseInt(ball.style.left) - 1 + 'px';
        ball.style.top = parseInt(ball.style.top) - 1 + 'px';
        animate = setTimeout(shootLeft,20);
    }
    if(ran<0.3){
        score = score + 1;
        document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score;
         {
            cheer.play();
            return;
        }

    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score;
    }
    x++;
    if(x==10){
        document.getElementById('gameover').innerHTML = "Game over! You got a score of " + score;
    }
    ball.style.left = '300px';
    ball.style.top = '410px';
}

function shootRight()
{
    var ran = Math.random();

    while (parseInt(ball.style.top != 300))
    {
        ball.style.left = parseInt(ball.style.left) + 1 + 'px';
        ball.style.top = parseInt(ball.style.top) - 1 + 'px';
        animate = setTimeout(shootRight,20);
    }
    if(ran>0.7){
        score = score + 1;
        document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score;
        {
            cheer.play();
            return;
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score;
    }
    x++;
    if(x==10){
        document.getElementById('gameover').innerHTML = "Game over! You got a score of " + score;
    }
    ball.style.left = '300px';
    ball.style.top = '410px';
}
</script>
```

Comment: It will be nice to see the `HTML` markup with a fully working example to experiment.

Comment: can you try putting it on this https://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: I uploaded it to codepen https://codepen.io/ldonahue00/pen/rgBYpK